# replace regex does not work in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with a column of string. within the string there are single quote which I want to get rid of all single quotes.for example:

```
"''hey, hey, we're the monkees''"
```

my regex works perfect and select all the values containing single quotes.

```
select regexp_replace(colName, '%''%', '') from tblName;
```

but it does not update my table when I want to replace this regex with nothing.

```
UPDATE tblName SET colName = regexp_replace(colName, '%''%', '');
```

I also checked this one

```
UPDATE tblName SET colName = replace(colName, '%''%', '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different functions and operators in Postgres use one of three different pattern matching languages, as [described in a dedicated section of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

The `%` form you are using here is the SQL `LIKE` syntax, where `%` represents "any number of any character". But the function you are using, `regexp_replace`, expects a Posix regular expression, where the equivalent would be `.*` (`.` meaning any character, `*` meaning repeat zero or more times).

Also note that `LIKE` expressions have to match the whole string, but a Posix regex doesn't, unless you explicitly match the start of the string with `^` and the end with `$`.

So the direct translation of `'%''%'` would be `'^.*''.*$'`, giving you this:

```
UPDATE tblName SET colName = regexp_replace(colName, '^.*''.*$', '');
```

In practice, this would give the same effect as the simpler:

```
UPDATE tblName SET colname='' WHERE colname LIKE '%''%';
```

Your actual use case is much simpler: you want to replace all occurrences of a fixed string (`'`, which will need to be quoted and escaped as `''''`) with another fixed string (the empty string, written `''`). So you don't need any pattern matching at all, just straight replacement using [`replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
UPDATE tblName SET colname=replace(colname, '''', '');
```

This will probably be faster if you limit it to rows that contain an apostrophe to begin with:

```
UPDATE tblName SET colname=replace(colname, '''', '') WHERE colname LIKE '%''%';
```

Comment: this one remove the values but I just want to remove the single quotes!

Comment: @Raha1986 I've updated the answer based on your clarification, please read to the end.

Comment: that is funny!
the same query does not work for "(".
I thought it should be the same as single quotes!

Comment: could you please tell that the same query should not work for "(" or ")"

Comment: I couldn't tell you without seeing exactly what you're trying, but `UPDATE tblName SET colname=replace(colname, '(', '') WHERE colname LIKE '%(%';` should work just fine. Maybe you just made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

% is not an regexp character

try this

```
select regexp_replace(colName, $$'$$, '','g') from tblName;
```

($$ is use to surround your string instead of ' to simplify the query)
(,'g') is use to continue after the first quote is found.

```
 UPDATE tblName SET colName = regexp_replace(colName, $$'$$, '','g');
```

Comment: Baron there is something wrong about the query, after the first quote, it makes rest of the query, purpleish

Comment: execute it anyway, editors do not recognize $$ but postgresql serveur recognise it, it's just a display problem. if you want you can use regexp_replace(colName, '''', '','g') but it's not very readable

Comment: I want to just remove the single quotes not remove whole the value!

Comment: I think the readability is a matter of taste. On a short string like this, I find `$$'$$` harder to read than `''''`, and it has the bonus of being the same in other DBMSes.

Comment: @IMSoP : I'm totally agree , it's a matter of taste , and for this example it's not very usefull but when you're manipulating complex string you don't have to protect all your quotes and others characters and that's protect your request against injections, It's what is used by postgres when you define a function for exemple ($BODY$ ... your code... $BODY$) .

Comment: @RémyBaron To be really pedantic, it's what's used by *a lot of clients* when *displaying* functions, and commonly used by humans *writing* functions; inside the DB, the definition is a string value like any other, and doesn't need to be quoted or escaped. But absolutely, for that case dollar-quoting is an absolute godsend; I tend to think of it as the Postgres equivalent of "heredocs", and use it in similar circumstances. I would absolutely *never* use it as a defence against injection, though; that's just security through obscurity, because it's probably no harder to inject a `$` than a `'`.

Comment: :) effectively i'm alright with all what you say. The use of dollard quoted string could be a very long discussion. For injection I don't use simple $$ but dollard quoted like $qlsk!!dfsdie$My comlex text with ' " and every thing$qlsk!!dfsdie$ generated by code. (And only when i can't use preparedStatements)