# how to remove quotes and numbers after stopwords removed from String in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, full-text-search, stop-words

I had a table with a string column. I removed the stopwords from the string and then the result look like this (which somehow connected to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959580/replace-regex-does-not-work-in-postgresql/41960113#41960113) and What @IMSoP suggested for another case)

```
'would':2 'yellow':4
```

I want to get rid of these quotes and : and the numbers. I tried

```
UPDATE tblName SET colName= replace(colName, '\s?[a-zA-Z]\w:\d', '');
```

and also this

```
UPDATE tblName SET colName= replace(colName, ':\d', '');
```

but for selection, it works but does not replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `regexp_replace()`?

```
UPDATE tblName
    SET colName = regexp_replace(colName, '[0-9:'']', '', 'g');
```